# History of line integral.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, math-history

I'm looking for some information about how the line integral was discovered, since I've been looking for a long time for this.

I found that Riemann could integer discontinuity functions, then Poisson said that the definite integral could vary if the interval is real or imaginary, saying that the integral depends on the travel, which is the basis of the concept of the line integral.

So it would be helpful to find something more related to it.

Comment: I would like it too!

Comment: Wow, no answers after 3 years. Disappointing.

Comment: I suggest migration to the [History of Math and Science StackExchange site](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/). A quick search shows that at least this is not a direct duplicate of existing posts. It seems that @Arturo is no longer active. Any user with 3k+ rep care to help clean up the site a bit? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The paper by Katz (1981) gives a detailed account of the historical development of differential forms. He credits a 1760 paper by Joseph-Louis Lagrange for the first development of the concept of line integration. His motivation was to understand the kinematics of wire. Line integration and the material derivative are important concepts in fluid dynamics, which was a major focus for mathematical physics in the 1700's.

Katz, V.J., 1981, The history of differential forms from Clairaut to Poincare, Historia Mathematica v. 8, p. 161-188

Lagrange, J. 1760. Application de la méthode exposée dans le mémoire précédent à la solution de différents problèmes de dynamique, Miscellanea Taurinensia, v. 2, p. 196-298.