Is "work" a natively physical or natively mathematical concept?
I recently watched a wonderful video explaining the Cauchy and Residue theorems, and how a complex integral's components relate to work done by and flux from the Polya vector field of the function being integrated on the curve being traversed.
Someone in the comments of that video expressed anger at the explanation saying "this is work done" or "this is flux", when according to them those are physical exclusive concepts and not satisfying conclusions in the complex plane.
I disagree with them, but I have to respect the point they're trying to make.
It's interesting to me, I don't have the literature knowledge to solve this chicken-or-egg problem. I learned about work and flux first from physics. As one might know:
$$
\int_C \vec F \cdot d{\vec r} \\
\iint _S \vec F \cdot \boldsymbol {\hat n}dS
$$
These are (my comfortable) definitions of work and flux respectively. They don't say anything about physical processes at all. By some incredibly useful miracle, the first integral equals the "change in kinetic energy", whatever that really means, and both can be tied to countless physical scenarios, especially in things like Maxwell's equations.
But my question really is, which practice claimed these first? Did math define these first, only for physicists to realize they were incredibly important? Or did physics discover these relationships first and realize there needed to be new mathematical notation for them? Which practice do these concepts "belong to"?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139637/history-of-line-integral

Clearly physical. In math , there is no concept of "work".
